# How to get info/data from blocked web sites with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, scripting, vpn

I want to write a script with python 3.7. But first I have to **scrape** it.
I have no problems with connecting and getting data from un-banned sites, but if the site is banned it won't work.

If I use a VPN service I can enter these "banned" sites with Chrome browser.

I tried setting a proxy in pycharm, but I failed. I just got errors all the time.
What's the simplest and free way to solve this problem?

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

req = Request('https://www.SOMEBANNEDSITE.com/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # that web site is blocked in my country

webpage = urlopen(req).read() # code stops running at this line because it can't connect to the site. 

page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to **scrape** blocked sites. A solid way is to use a proxy service as already mentioned.

A proxy server, also known as a "proxy"  is a computer that acts as a gateway between your computer and the internet.
When you are using a proxy, you requests are being forwarded through the proxy. Your ip is not directly exposed to the site that you are **scraping**.

You cant simply take any ip (say xxx.xx.xx.xxx) and port (say yy) do

```
import requests

proxies = { 'http': "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:yy", 
            'https': "https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:yy"}

r = requests.get('http://www.somebannedsite.com', proxies=proxies)
```

and expect to get a response.

The proxy should be configured to take your request and send you a response.

so, where can you get a proxy?

a. You could buy proxies from many providers.

b. Use a list of free proxies from the internet.

You don't need to buy proxies unless you are doing some massive scale **scraping**.
For now i will focus on free proxies available on the internet. Just do a google search for "free proxy provider" and you will find a list of sites offering free proxies. Go to any one of them and get any `ip` and corresponding `port`.

```
import requests

#replace the ip and port below with the ip and port you got from any of the free sites

proxies = { 'http': "http://182.52.51.155:39236", 
            'https': "https://182.52.51.155:39236"}

r = requests.get('http://www.somebannedsite.com', proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)
```

You should if possible use a proxy having 'Elite' anonymity level (the anonymity level will be specified in most of the sites providing the free proxy). If interested you could also do a google searh to find the difference between 'elite', 'anonymous' and 'transparent' proxies.

Note:

Most of these free proxies are not that reliable. So if you get error with one ip and port combination. try a different one.

Comment: I have tried everything (and your solution) and I still get this error:

blablablabla......(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request')))

I have tried multiple hosts and all were the same. I don't care about anonymity right now. But I just want this to work. Please help me man I'm going insane for 2 days. why does this happening? i shuttet down my firewall, still getting the error

Comment: @blackwater111 Hi just go to https://free-proxy-list.net/  and get a different proxy and ip combination from there. I know this is frustrating for you but try it out.

Comment: @blackwater111 can you give the site you are trying to scrap? I can try it out from my end.

Comment: @blackwater111 I will update my answer and let you know. I don't think you can use requests, might need selenium. Also consider removing your earlier comment. People of various age groups visit SO.

Comment: ok i removed it. Some other guy also suggested selenium but i have a question, can i do some queries with selenium? i like scraping so, for example can i pick the videos longer than 30mins, and which released after 2015. stuff like that.... does that work with selenium? also people said it so slow. is this correct?

Comment: @blackwater111 i think so.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution would be to use a proxy via the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. This would be the best solution for you since it has the capability of [flexibly handling the requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) via a proxy.

Here is a small example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
# use your usable proxies here
# replace host with you proxy IP and port with port number
proxies = { 'http': "http://host:port", 
            'https': "https://host:port"} 

text = requests.get('http://www.somebannedsite.com', proxies=proxies, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
page_soup = soup(text, "html.parser") # use whatever parser you prefer, maybe lxml?
```

If you want to use SOCKS5, then you'd have to get the dependencies via `pip install requests[socks]` and then replace the proxies part by:

```
# user is your authentication username
# pass is your auth password
# host and port are similar as above
proxies = { 'http': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port', 
            'https': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port' }
```

If you don't have proxies at hand, you can [fetch some proxies](https://github.com/stamparm/fetch-some-proxies).

Comment: If you have the time can you write the exact code please? Because I have tried using requests library for whole day and I still couldn't managed to get it work. Only thing I want is getting some simple data from that banned site.

Comment: Just tried your code and it didn't return anything. Are these adresses & ports are correct, or I have to find some working ones? Really thanks for the effort btw.

Comment: I still have problems. First of all, just to be sure: Is this the correct way to import proxies?

proxies = { 'http': "194.228.129.189:50946",
            'https': "194.228.129.189:50946", }

If so, this code didn't work. I got a huge error list when I run it.

Also I  get these proxies from google, I just google free proxy list, would they work?

Comment: No, your proxies must have the scheme (http:// or https://) before the IP address. Have a look at the [official docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) about handling proxies. You'd understand better.

Comment: My bad, I fixed it but I still have the problem. Still doesn't work. I'd paste the error debug here but it's too long, it won't let me do this

Comment: Tell me what the error is like the last few lines will do.

Comment: File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\3.7_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.BANNED.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /remaining_link_of_BANNED/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A10DD8E400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))

Comment: Yeah it happens, your proxy isn't responding or refusing connections. Try using a low latency proxy with a valid set of headers emulating browser. Or [fetch some proxies](https://github.com/stamparm/fetch-some-proxies). Any standard proxy should be up and working with my code.

Comment: So its all about the proxies Im trying? I will try to find some good ones with low latency, but even if this solve the problem I feel like it wont last much.
Does fetching proxies is some advanced stuff? i just started using python like a week ago, and i really need to fix my issue :(

Comment: I'm really glad you tried hard but my issue is still not fixed so I can't accept your answer yet. Edit: just realised you edited your post, checking it now

Comment: God, I feel like I won't be able to fix this, ever. What is my authentication username and pass? How can I see it?

Comment: You really don't know what your doing, do you?

Comment: Tell me what more I can help you with. I wrote out the entire source for you, Gave you links where you can find usable proxies. All you need is to run the tool, get some valid proxies, and run it accordingly.

Comment: If you can give me one "working" code, you will have my respect and i will upvote all your comments. The problem is, I feel like whatever I try, it won't work. Because this is what happened in the last 2 days., I just get some new errors every code I run and I'm so tired. So I just want to be sure that there is actually a way to solve this. I want to believe this. But if it takes too much time of yours, I understand.